# awk search for a paragraph by a word from a file using shell variables

Tags: variables, awk

I try filer file by name and previously asked how to use a shell variable in awk
[How to force awk command search for a previously given word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456194/how-to-force-awk-command-search-for-a-previously-given-word)

Using recommendations given I can't now get the whole paragraph, only the name given... My question is: how can I get paragraphs, which consist the name given? Paragraphs are separated by \n\n

```
awk '{print var}' var="$NAME" RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" literatur.bib
```

It worked perfectly this way, but I had to write the name direct in awk, which doesn't match the task

```
awk '/name/' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" literatur.bib
```

Input should look like this: Newton

Output like this, but with all the paragraphs with the name Newton:

> @Book{Eilam:2005:reversing,
>   author =   {Eldad Newton},   title =
>   {Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering},
>   publisher =    {Wiley}, 
>   year =     2005 }
>
> @Book{Glatz:2006:Betriebssysteme,
>   author =   {Eduard Newton},
>   title =    "{Betriebssysteme}",   publisher =      {dpunkt},   year =      2006 }

Input file looks exactly like this example, but consist of hundreds of the similar paragraphs

When I search for example name Baruah I become this:

```
Baruah

Baruah

Baruah
```

And so many more times... And it just prints it without search, because if I would give the word not given in the file I will still become this result - this word written many times

SOLVED:

Just by using "" instead of ''

```
awk "/name/" RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" literatur.bib
```

Comment: Welcome to SO could you please do provide sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Done. Hopefully it is ok)

Comment: word/string searching is fine, please provide sample of input file where we need to search this. Kindly edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Input file looks exactly as the output example, but consists hundreds of a similar paragraphs...

Comment: No, sorry still not clear. Please mention sample input file too so that we could see clearly which lines it is picking and which not, kindly edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Sorry, is it now clear?

Comment: I tried this way as well:  awk -v var="$NAME" '{print var}'  RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" literatur.bib
Result is the same

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts which you are trying to explain, but it should be simply. Sample of input, sample of expected output.  To me sample input is still not clear,if you could make it clear could try to help more, cheers.

Comment: I can't understand, what else do I have to give... Input is just a name... Previous program lines have nothing to do with a problem because it is just   echo "Give the name please: "
read NAME